# Android - View.GONE is the right way?

Tags: android, memory

I'm making an application which generate dynamically a layout and all the views inside it. When a user press a button, I need to delete the **layout** (with all the views inside it) and regenerate it with new informations.
I've looked for a solution, and I found the following method:

```
View.GONE
```

My question is if this is the right way to proceed, because I don't know if a user delete and remake the layout 100 times, how much memory this thing uses. `View.GONE` doesn't clear up the memory for what I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the inside views are referred to as Child Views. So if you want to remove a child view, you can call the `removeView (View view)`

If you want to remove all the views:

```
viewGroup.removeAllViews()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()

Comment: I don't want to remove a child view, but I want to remove the layout which contains the child views, so i can remove all just by deleting the layout

Comment: Seen now your edit. removeAllViews can be the solution. So with it i can remove all the views i add to a layout, right?

Comment: With only removeView() method you can achieve what you want. You can have nested views. That is, your first child views will be layouts and these child layouts in turn may contain additional views. Now you can simply add/remove outer child views (layout) by parent.addView() and parent.removeView()

"parent" here is the outermost layout defined in the layout xml file. Hope you're understanding what I'm trying to say

Comment: Yes i understand and this is the solution i'll use. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a view by:

```
((ViewManager)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
```

Otherwise if you are wanting to repopulate with new data, you can just change the content/text in the views instead of deleting them. Either way.

**Edit**

To remove a layout would be the way you suggested.

```
findViewById(R.id.layout).setVisibiliy(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I don't want to remove a view, but I want to remove a layout, with all the views inside.

Comment: Ok, so i ask again my question, if a user delete and remake the layout 100 times, is this an incredible memory usage?

Comment: Once the view is gone it is removed from memory. So it shouldn't be a huge memory load.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Anyway, i'll use the solution proposed by zeus (viewGroup.removeAllViews()). Thank you